# Create table query gives me "table does not exists" error

Tags: php, mysql, database, drupal-7, innodb

My local Drupal site is crashed.

This is the error:
`PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drupal722.semaphore' doesn't exist: SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => variable_init ) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of D:\Projects\wamp\www\drupal\includes\lock.inc).`

`Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#039;drupal722.semaphore&#039; doesn&#039;t exist: DELETE FROM {semaphore} WHERE (value = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; 573260675528605a31630a6.23576489 ) in lock_release_all() (line 269 of D:\Projects\wamp\www\drupal\includes\lock.inc).`

Then i googled about how to solve this error and found that i will have to create a table. So i fired a query to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `semaphore` (
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique name.',
    `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'A value for the semaphore.',
    `expire` double NOT NULL COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp with microseconds indicating when the semaphore should expire.',
    PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
    KEY `value` (`value`),
    KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Table for holding semaphores, locks, flags, etc. that...';`
```

But to my surprise, it is giving below error:(`drupal722` is my database name)

`#1146 - Table 'drupal722.semaphore' doesn't exist`

Now, i have two **big** questions:

1. Why `Create table` query is giving me "table does not exists" error. It is much obvious that i know that table does not exists and so i want to create table and so i am firing a query of `Create table`.
2. How to resolve above mentioned error related to Drupal to get my site back to work?

BTW, i have already asked this question on drupal.stackexchange.com [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94320/create-table-query-gives-me-table-does-not-exists-error) but no fruitful results So i am asking here again.

After posting question on drupal.stackexchange.com and having discussions with few people there, i have already tried below query:

```
CREATE TABLE `semaphore` (
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique name.',
    `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'A value for the semaphore.',
    `expire` double NOT NULL COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp with microseconds indicating when the semaphore should expire.',
    PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
    KEY `value` (`value`),
    KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Table for holding semaphores, locks, flags, etc. that...';`
```

but the problem persists. the error is same with this query too...

Comment: Are you able to create other tables? Try with a simple `CREATE TABLE ...` statement (without the `IF NOT EXISTS` part). And then do a `SHOW TABLES`. Do you have anything there?

Comment: Tell me about your operative system...

Comment: What user are you connecting with? Perhaps the user doesn't have the rights required to execute `CREATE` statements?

Comment: @RobertRozas: Windows

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: If the user dont have permissions then the error should be different. Dont you think so?

Comment: @AmalMurali: when i fired `Show tables`, it shows table `semaphore` in the list along with other tables. But, no operation is allowed on `semaphore`. Neither select, nor rename query works for that table.

Comment: @BhavikShah: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @AmalMurali: `Table 'drupal722.semaphore' doesn't exist` when i tried to create table. `Table 'drupal722.semaphore' doesn't exists` when i tried to rename / select data from that table

Comment: And if you use a software like Heidi Sql http://www.heidisql.com/ ....then connect to your database and create your table?...just for testing purposes

Comment: @RobertRozas: Well, i have already used `HeidiSQL` in past. But whats the point if i am getting error on console...

Comment: So you are on mysql console??....what is your database name...before to create your table in mysql console you have to run this command: use drupal722(or your drupal database name);

Comment: @RobertRozas: I am working on PMA but i have tried to fire query directly on console too to cross-check the query but found same error on both PMA and console. Moreover, i know that i have to select database before firing queries of table. That is not the problem. The problem is "When i fire `Show tables` then `semaphore` is listed along with other tables of database but when i try to perform some operation the it says `table doesn't exists`"

Comment: so you can create table with diff name and same structure on your drupal database, right?....why don't your try this: 1- create table same structure diff name(ej: test) , 2- drop table semaphore, 3- rename table test to semaphore; in that order.

Comment: @RobertRozas: I have tried this approach. Step-1 success. Step-2 error `table doesn't exists`. So, there is no meaning of performing Step-3

Comment: Show me your mysql dir structure on (bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data)....i need to check that

Comment: As a last resort try `DROP TABLE`, Then `SHOW TABLES`.

Answer (score 0):

Many of drupal users getting this issue, check this https://drupal.org/node/1308308 link it may help you.

try to just delete setting.php file and copy past default.setting.php file and rename with settting.php file then try to access site.